# Validate if exist before insert into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

[image]

I have to read a txt data that contains a first load that someone do, and insert data into 2 tables. this means:

1. At the begining tab_data and tab_list is empty.
2. with the first txt record, i have to validate first if "C43R" exist on "tab_list" table, if not, i have to insert and get the new ID, and after that insert that new ID created on "tab_data" table with the rest of information.
3. With the second record, first i have to validate if "C43R" exist on "tab_list" table, if exist i have to get the ID, and after that insert that new ID created on "tab_data" table with the rest of information.
4. with the fourth txt record, i have to validate first if "M23K" exist on "tab_list" table, if not, i have to insert and get the new ID, and after that insert that new ID created on "tab_data" table with the rest of information.

And the same with all the rows from the txt file.

**So how can i start with this?**

Does any body have a suggestion or a solution?

Really thanks, regards

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two queries. The logic would be to first feed `tab_list`, then `tab_data`. Note that you need an ordering column in `txt_data` for this to make sense - I assumed `id`.

This `insert`s into `tab_list`, while manually generating a sequence that starts at `10`.

```
insert into tab_list(id, tab)
select tab_id, 9 + row_number() over(order by min(id)) 
from txt_data
group by tab_id
```

With this set-up at hand, you can then `insert` in `tab_data`:

```
insert into tab_data (id, tab_id, data)
select
    99 + row_number() over(order by d.id),
    l.id,
    d.data
from txt_data d
inner join tab_list l on l.tab_id = d.tab_id
```